# Android Stripe integration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, stripe-payments

I have tried to integrate `Stripe` with my project. I have gone through the integration guide from https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android. And I keep receiving an error `Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2`.

I have put into my build.gradle file `Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:8.0.0`. Additionally, I have found the GitHub project that version varies from the one in the guide and I have tried it. The version number in the GitHub project is `8.0.0`.

Full error log:

[image]

The short version of my dependencies in gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.0.0'

    ...
}
```

Is there any additional maven repo or something that I should add to the gradle to be able to add this dependency to the project?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android but it does does not matter, `7.0.1` does not work too

Comment: its working fine. You just need to check whether you have added jcenter() in you repositories part in project level gradle file.

Comment: @AshishJohn yes I have `jcenter()` in my project level gradle

Comment: can you please add that too in your question

Comment: did you enable offline work for gradle?

Comment: @Redman <- offline work was enabled for the gradle and it was causing the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok let me add answer for future readers

Comment: @Redman sure thing!

Comment: Recently I have used stripe in project, I also got this issue at development time. So I added stripe demo as module and It 's working fine for me. you also can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have enabled offline work for gradle,

[image]

Uncheck the box and sync the project again . It should fix the problem.